# Is there a way to do an Upload Progress Indicator for CarrierWave / Fog?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, carrierwave, fog

I'm using CarrierWave / Fog in a Rails application to upload videos to Amazon S3.

Is there a way to determine the progress of the upload, so that I can display
the upload progress being made?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

CarrierWave and Fog don't have that kind of functionality natively; you'll need a front-end uploader to display progress stuff. When I had to solve this problem I used [jQuery file upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) because I already had jQuery in my stack. There's even [a post on CarrierWave integration](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Rails-setup-for-V6) so you can just follow the instructions there to get a progress bar working for your app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  Client decided not to do a full progress indicator, but this tip will come in handy in the future I'm sure.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this,

https://groups.google.com/group/ruby-fog/msg/45e8f0a63d973a6b